# JQuery - SVG loaded to div doesn't move with div

Tags: jquery, svg

I have an SVG loaded into a div via jQuery. The div is `position: absolute`.

When I set that div to `position: left` the div moves but not the SVG. How can I move the div and the SVG?

```
$('#case_1_btn').one('click', function() {
  $('#image_placeholder').load('cases/case_1/images/case_1_1.svg', function() {
    var svg = $('#image_placeholder').find('svg')[0];
    svg.setAttribute('height', '70%');  
    $('#image_placeholder').css('left', '70%');

    $('#case_text_container').load('cases/case_1/case_1_start.html');
  }); 
});
```

After the `$('#case_1_btn')` is clicked, `$('#image_placeholder')` is changed to position left 70% ok, but the SVG is not moving with it:

[image]

Comment: `position: left`??????

Comment: $('#image_placeholder').css('left', '70%'); should work.  The element is set to position absolute in the external css

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

         $('#case_1_btn').one('click', function(){
        $('#image_placeholder').load('cases/case_1/images/case_1_1.svg', function() {
            var svg = $('#image_placeholder').find('svg')[0];
            svg.setAttribute('height', '70%');
            svg.removeAttribute("viewBox");  // <--- ADD THIS
            $('#image_placeholder').css('left', '600');
         $('#case_text_container').load('cases/case_1/case_1_start.html');
        });
});

    });
```